# Push Git Repository as new repository to Gitlab with jgit

Tags: java, git, gitlab, jgit

I have a git repository on my computer and want to push it as new git repository to a Gitlab instance.

I tried:

```java
Path tempCloneDir = Files.createTempDirectory("git");

Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
  .setURI(localGit.getLocalGitRepo()
      .toString())
  .setDirectory(tempCloneDir.toFile())
  .call();

git.push()
  .setCredentialsProvider(
      new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("gitlab-ci-token", gitlabToken))
  .setRemote(localGit.getGitlabUrl())
  .setPushAll()
  .call();
```

This creates a repository, but it only pushes the main branch and ignores all tags.

I also tried to add `.setPushTags()`, but still, the other branches are missing.

What do I need to change to push "everything"?

Comment: Did you [clone all branches](https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/6.4.0.202211300538-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CloneCommand.html#setCloneAllBranches(boolean))?

Comment: Alternatively, you could try [opening the local repository using `Git.open`](https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/6.4.0.202211300538-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/Git.html#open(java.io.File)) instead of cloning it to a temporary directory (assuming it's actually local as I don't know what exactly `localGit` is).

Answer (score 0):

Following dan1st's advice, I solved the problem by using:

```java
 try (Git openedRepo = Git.open(localGit.getLocalGitRepo()
          .toFile());)
      {
        Iterable<PushResult> pushResults = openedRepo.push()
            .setCredentialsProvider(
                new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("gitlab-ci-token", gitlabToken))
            .setRemote(localGit.getGitlabUrl())
            .setPushTags()
            .setPushAll()
            .call();
       }
```